# django errors with img/loading.gif

Tags: python, django

I dont know why I am getting this error..

```
[06/Feb/2015 08:04:18] "GET /static/images/bg.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1643
[06/Feb/2015 08:04:18] "GET /static/images/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 404  1658
[06/Feb/2015 08:04:18] "GET /img/major/main_bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 11090
[06/Feb/2015 08:04:18] "GET /img/loading.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 11072
[06/Feb/2015 08:04:18] "GET /img/a07.png HTTP/1.1" 404 11060
```

Locally I dont have any problem with this but in deployment it gives alot of problem. My site totally becomes slow and throws internal server error..

Why I am getting this error

Comment: did you set up your `static_root url` in your settings.py file?

Comment: yeah I do... There is not a problem in frontend or anywhere...

Comment: what server are you using to serve static files ? or are you using apache ? or what ?

Comment: yes I am using apache

Comment: Do those files exist on the server? And what internal server errors are you getting? Your site should not be slow because you get 404's on images.

Comment: I have set STATIC_ROOT = ' ' in my settings.py ... Do this make my site slow.. Also when I try to upload image either from admin or client it says permission denied and internal server error... It takes alot of time to upload image and failed... No image is uploaded... I waited till 30 mins and at last internal server error and permission denied

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you forgot to run`python manage.py collectstatic` on your server.
That dosen't affect the `runserver` command but the real webserver.